# How to configure SHIFT+LEFT, SHIFT+RIGHT, SHIFT+HOME and SHIFT+END keys in terminal on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, selection, key-binding

To configure the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys in terminal on MacBook Air (OS X 10.7.2) I defined in `Terminal -> Preferences -> Keyboard`:

```
Key     Action
----    ------
Home    \033OH
End     \033OF
```

What are the codes to configure the following combinations so that they will work like in Windows?

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> (should select the character on the left)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> (should select the character on the right)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> (should select all the characters on the left)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> (should select all the characters on the right)

Comment: You do realize that *xterm* and *Terminal.app* are not the same?

Comment: I'm not sure... Could you explain please? How does this help me to do the desired keybindings?

Comment: It doesn't. But your question is misleading: There's absolutely no connection to `xterm` with what you want to do.

Comment: OK, I deleted `xterm` from the question.

Comment: What kind of selection are we talking about, do you mean the terminal selection (when click and drag with the mouse), or the shell selection (when you press `C-space`). They are different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `read` command to determine the keybinding sequence followed by your required keys

Add the output to the below file prefixed with  `"\e`[your sequence]`"`

Create a file in your home directory `~/` called .inputrc

```
$ vim ~/.inputrc
```

I have the following setup for ctrl + left , right, up, down and home and end keys

```
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

Restart Terminal.app and your good to go.

Comment: The question is about *selection*, not *movement*.

Answer (score 0):

```
Key            Action
----           ------
Home           \033OH
End            \033OF
Shift+Left     \033[1;2C
Shift+Right.   \033[1;2D
Shift+Home.    \022[1;2H
Shift+End.     \022[1;2F
```